# css - div height 100% not working

Tags: css

I have set the height of the div's parent element, body, to 100% and the div is still not 100% high. I have checked the code it looks right and I am not high.

Please help

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FhpIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you forgot about the `<html>` element: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KFmJv

ALL of the parents need to be set to 100% height in order to get 100% height working on an element, even the HTML element

Comment: Thanks! When I looked at your profile, however, it seems that you never accept answers. If an answer works for you and answers the question, you can click the check below the vote count to "accept" the answer

Comment: I've been a developer for a long time and I just found this. Amazing that 100% width works out of <body> but not 100% height.